# Words associated with throwing things, specifically the action of throwing a paper airplane

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

What word(s) would you use to describe throwing something, specifically during the action of throwing a paper airplane?

The one word I was able to come up with was "flick", but I'm looking for other synonyms.

Thanks!

Comment: How about "*launch*"?

Comment: I think we always used "throw" or "toss" when I was a kid.

Comment: [How to throw paper planes](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/going-deep-with-david-rees/interactives/getting-graphically-deep-with-david-rees-how-to-throw-a-paper-airplane/)

Answer (score 1):

**throw** is the verb used in the rules for the *Longest paper aircraft flight* in the [Guinness Book of World Records](http://challengers.guinnessworldrecords.com/challenges/12-longest-paper-aircraft-flight/attempts/245).

> You must throw your aircraft from a stationary position on a flat
>   surface at the same level or below that which the aircraft lands on.

**throw** and **launch** are both used in the [Red Bull Paper Wings International Qualiflyer Rules](http://www.redbullpaperwings.com/Rules.html)

> - The aircraft must be launched by one person throwing the aircraft unaided from a reasonably static position. The participant needs to
>     have both feet firm on the ground during the attempt.
> - A run-up or fast walk as part of the launch is not permitted, nor the use of ramps or like devices.

Answer (score 0):

a few more ideas.  Some of these are incomplete without saying something about where it's going.

hurl, jettison, give a push, propel, aim, lob, pitch, send, set in motion, initiate flight, chuck, fling, release.

Answer (score 0):

A paper air plane ***whizzed*** past my ears.

The boys **aimed** the paper air planes at their aunt and ***flung*** them.

He is an expert in ***propelling*** paper air planes.